# How can I tell if a Vue component is unmounted to prevent async function accessing unmounted component's data?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Please see this minimum example

```
import Vue from 'vue';

Vue.extend({
  data() {
    return {
      name: 'James',
    };
  },
  methods: {
    greet() {
      setTimeout(() => {
        const componentIsUnmounted = ???; // How do I tell if component is unmounted?

        if (!componentIsUnmounted) {
          console.log(this.name);
        }
      }, 300);
    },
  },
});
```

As you can see, I have a component with an async function, it will be triggered after 300ms when you called it, by that time, the Vue component might be unmounted.

I think I can do this by storing a flag in the global via Lodash's [`uniqueID()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#uniqueId) function to create a unique ID at `mounted()` and `beforeDestroyed()`.

Is there another easyier way to do that?

Comment: Which component and why will be unmounted?

Comment: unsure what you are trying to do here but you might be able to utilize `clearTimeout()` which is a native javascript function

Comment: I'm performing an async function, the async function will access the component's data, in that 300ms time, the component might be unmounted by other people, the async action what I want to do is actually debounce, but I simplify the question with a setTimeout

Comment: Not sure you need a global flag for this. You can just set a boolean flag/property on the component instance itself and check that within your timer callback function. Vue already has a private property called `_isBeingDestroyed` that I tend to use for this purpose but it is private so use it at your own risk. If possible I'd suggest using `clearTimeout` instead to cancel the timer within your `beforeDestroy` hook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that it would be best if you can control the timeout (using `clearTimeout()`, for example, as suggested on the comments). In your case, as you're using a `debounce`, depending on what lib you're using, you might not have that control.

In this case, one suggestion is to mix [`Node.contains`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains) with [`vm.$el`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-el). As follows:

```js
export default {
  methods: {
    greet() {
      const isUnmounted = !document.body.contains(this.$el)
    }
  }
}
```

Other alternative is to use [`destroyed`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#destroyed) lifecycle to control this state internally.

---

I've provided a guiding example that might help you: https://codesandbox.io/s/smoosh-frost-fdisj.

---

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I just used and it worked great.

When you create the timeout, store the ID on `this`. Then on `beforeDestroy`, call `clearTimeout` with the ID. Even if you manually cancel the timeout beforehand, `clearTimeout` will not fail.

```
<script>
  export default {
    created() {
      this.timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {}, 1000)
    },

    beforeDestroy() {
      clearTimeout(this.timeoutId)
    }
  }
</script>
```

No need to set it in the `data` property, as it isn't reactive.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the beforeDestroy event like below :

```
  mounted() {
    this.$once("hook:beforeDestroy", () => {
      //...
    })
  }
```